# Using product and average formula in python to create a loss rate table

Tags: python, excel, pandas, data-science

I am trying to create Loss rate table (see below) from the flow rate data frame I already have in python. Appreciate if someone can help me with the code. I have reproduced excel formulas below, but let me know if you need more information.

excel formula in cell B8 of loss rate table is `=PRODUCT(B2:$H$2)`. This formula has been applied to the whole table, for example in cell C3 I have used `=PRODUCT(C3:$H$3)`.

Finally, average in formula in row 13 is simple average of columns after calculating the loss rate. i.e. Formula in B13 is `=AVERAGE(B8:B12)`

thanks in advance for your help!

|  | Flow Rate |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| 1 | Month | NYD | DPD30 | DPD60 | DPD90 | DPD120 | DPD150 | Loss |
| 2 | Feb | 0.40 | 0.70 | 0.63 | 0.50 | 0.90 | 0.30 | 1.00 |
| 3 | Mar | 0.74 | 0.63 | 0.57 | 0.72 | 0.80 | 0.56 | 1.00 |
| 4 | Apr | 0.67 | 0.73 | 0.76 | 0.63 | 0.83 | 0.67 | 1.00 |
| 5 | May | 0.57 | 0.67 | 0.69 | 0.66 | 0.64 | 0.60 | 1.00 |
| 6 | June | 0.50 | 0.67 | 0.64 | 0.72 | 0.72 | 0.94 | 1.00 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | Loss rate |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H |
| 7 | Month | NYD | DPD30 | DPD60 | DPD90 | DPD120 | DPD150 | Loss |
| 8 | Feb | 0.02 | 0.06 | 0.08 | 0.14 | 0.27 | 0.30 | 1.00 |
| 9 | Mar | 0.08 | 0.11 | 0.18 | 0.32 | 0.44 | 0.56 | 1.00 |
| 10 | Apr | 0.13 | 0.19 | 0.26 | 0.35 | 0.56 | 0.67 | 1.00 |
| 11 | May | 0.07 | 0.12 | 0.17 | 0.25 | 0.38 | 0.60 | 1.00 |
| 12 | June | 0.10 | 0.21 | 0.31 | 0.49 | 0.68 | 0.94 | 1.00 |
| 13 | Average | 0.08 | 0.14 | 0.20 | 0.31 | 0.47 | 0.61 | 1.00 |

Comment: How is your data arranged in the dataframes?  could you give the dataframe output you expect in and what you expect out?

Comment: i tried copying df here but i was unable to copy paste in a readable form.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iloc` to get only the numeric portion of the data frame, then use the `apply` function with `cumprod` over the horizontal axis (`axis=1`) in reverse order (`x[::-1]`), evaluating the cumulative product over the data from right to left. This will produce the expected output described in the Loss rate table. To add the last row (`average`), calculate the `mean` and transform the resulting series into a transposed data frame. This data frame will then be concatenated to `df_loss` to achieve the expected result. If you want, you can then create the new `index` using the original `month` names and add the `Average` to it using `pd.Index`.

```py
import pandas as pd

d = {
'Month': {0: 'Feb ', 1: 'Mar ', 2: 'Apr ', 3: 'May ', 4: 'June '},
'NYD': {0: 0.4, 1: 0.74, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.57, 4: 0.5},
'DPD30': {0: 0.7, 1: 0.63, 2: 0.73, 3: 0.67, 4: 0.67},
'DPD60': {0: 0.63, 1: 0.57, 2: 0.76, 3: 0.69, 4: 0.64},
'DPD90': {0: 0.5, 1: 0.72, 2: 0.63, 3: 0.66, 4: 0.72},
'DPD120': {0: 0.9, 1: 0.8, 2: 0.83, 3: 0.64, 4: 0.72},
'DPD150': {0: 0.3, 1: 0.56, 2: 0.67, 3: 0.6, 4: 0.94},
'Loss': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0}}

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df)

df_loss = df.iloc[:, 1:].apply(lambda x: x[::-1].cumprod(), axis=1)
df_loss = df_loss[df.columns[1:]] # fix presentation order

dmean = pd.DataFrame(df_loss.mean()).T
df_loss = pd.concat([df_loss, dmean])

df_loss.index = pd.Index([*df.Month, "Average"], name="Month")

print(df_loss.round(3))
```

Output from *df_loss*

```py
           NYD  DPD30  DPD60  DPD90  DPD120  DPD150  Loss
Month
Feb      0.024  0.060  0.085  0.135   0.270   0.300   1.0
Mar      0.086  0.116  0.184  0.323   0.448   0.560   1.0
Apr      0.130  0.194  0.266  0.350   0.556   0.670   1.0
May      0.067  0.117  0.175  0.253   0.384   0.600   1.0
June     0.104  0.209  0.312  0.487   0.677   0.940   1.0
Average  0.082  0.139  0.204  0.310   0.467   0.614   1.0
```